# Override gcov functions to get executed code lines

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gcov

I'm want to get all executed code lines of project using gcov. For example code like:

```
int main()
{
   int i=0;
   for(i=0;i<3;i++)printf("Hello");
   return 0;
}
```

And result will be like:

```
1)int i=0;
2)for(i=0;i<3;i++)
3)printf("Hello");
4)for(i=0;i<3;i++)
5)printf("Hello");
6)for(i=0;i<3;i++)
7)printf("Hello");
8)for(i=0;i<3;i++)
9)return 0;
```

The main idea is to make own implementation of gcov functions by rewriting libgcov. After that use it in combination **gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage *test.c -o test* -lanothergcov**.

So, is it right to do such thing or it will not work, also has anyone any experience working with source code of gcov to get from it needed info, which it doesn't provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with simply rewriting libgcov. You'd have to rewrite the corresponding gcc code that injects the counter increment instruction inbetween every line.

After instrumentation your code will execute essentially as:

```
 crt0: 
     __gcov_init(main_locals);
     main();
     __gcov_exit(); // dump the counters to files

 int main() {
     static GcovStruct_t local;
     local.Counter[0]++;
     for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
     local.Counter[1]++;
     printf("Hello");
     local.Counter[2]++;
     }
     local.Counter[3]++;
 }
```

There maybe something to do though, as you can use
`<prompt> gcc -S -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` to get the intermediate .s file:

```
    movq    .LPBX1(%rip), %rax
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, .LPBX1(%rip)
```

This could be almost trivial to modify by search & replace into:

```
    movq    .LPBX1(%rip), %rax   -> leaq    .LPBX1(%rip), %rax
    addq     $1, %rax            -> pushq %rax
                                    call     __init_add_line_number_to_list
    movq    %rax, .LPBX1(%rip)   -> -- remove this --
```

Then you'd require the newly introduced routine to increment the qword pointer and to insert that address to some extra structure that would be processed by the gcov tools that you'd modify next.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
The main idea is that compiler shouldn't be touched, only using it's parametres,modified libraries (that can worked in gcc3 and gcc4 for example) get this info. So as I understood it could be done only by modyfieng gcc compilier, right am I?

Comment: Basically it requires gcc modification, but as I later showed, there exists an easy 1:1 mapping to modify gcc .s output for the purpose (in x64 architecture at least), which should work after recompiling: `gcc file.s -lmygcov`

Comment: Ok,(without any code, just idea,may be wrong): gcov puts as output on each line of code the count of it execution, so it knows how much the definite line executed - gcov can resolve that info  so it know's the line and it info.

Comment: That pretty much covers it. To do that gcov reads the runtime created file source_code.gcda and compile-time generated file source_code.gcdo.